# Load data local infile with IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, load-data-infile

I have table with data:

```
| id  | status |
+-----+--------+
|  1  |    1   |
|  2  |    1   |
|  3  |    0   |
|  4  |    2   |
|  5  |    2   |
```

I have file, that I need to load into this table and replace:

```
| id | status |  
+----+--------+
|  1 |    1   |  
|  2 |    0   |  
|  3 |    0   |  
|  4 |    0   |  
|  5 |    1   |
```

I have one condition: if status in table =2 and status in file =0, leave status in table =2, otherwise replace status in table from file.
After query I need to get new data:

```
| id  | status |  
+-----+--------+
|  1  |    1   |  
|  2  |    0   |  
|  3  |    0   |  
|  4  |    2   |  
|  5  |    1   |
```

I'm trying do it with query:

```
load data local
infile '".$file."'
replace
into table t1
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"'
(@tid, 
teacher_name, 
email,
@pid,   
tca_form_type, 
prod_company, 
prod_name,
@stts)
set status = if((select status from (select status from t1 where teacher_id=@tid and prod_id=@pid) as tmp)=2  and @stts=0,status,@stts),
teacher_id = @tid, prod_id = @pid
```

After that I get status fields NULL.
How to resolve this problem?

**Edit:**
I tried:

```
set status = if((select @var:=status from (select status from t1 where teacher_id=@tid and prod_id=@pid) as tmp)=2 and @stts=0,@var,@stts),
```

But result status 2 changed to 0.

**Table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`teacher_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`prod_id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `teacher_id_UNIQUE` (`teacher_id`, `prod_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
AUTO_INCREMENT=2053;
```

**Real data:**

```
| id  | teacher_id | status | prod_id |
+-----+------------+--------+---------+
|  1  |    a1      |    1   |    15   |
|  2  |    a1      |    1   |    16   |
|  3  |    a1      |    0   |    17   |
|  4  |    a2      |    2   |    16   |
|  5  |    a2      |    2   |    18   |
|  6  |    a3      |    0   |    15   |
|  7  |    a3      |    1   |    20   |
```

**File data:**

```
| teacher_id | status | prod_id |
+------------+--------+---------+
|    a1      |    0   |    15   |
|    a1      |    1   |    16   |
|    a1      |    0   |    17   |
|    a2      |    1   |    16   |
|    a2      |    0   |    18   |
|    a3      |    1   |    15   |
|    a3      |    1   |    20   |
```

**My temporary solution:**

```
load data local
                infile '".$file."'
                into table table_tmp
                fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"'
                (teacher_id, 
                teacher_name, 
                email,
                prod_id,   
                tca_form_type, 
                prod_company, 
                prod_name,
                status);
INSERT INTO table
                    (teacher_id, teacher_name, email, status, prod_id, tca_form_type, prod_company, prod_name)
                    SELECT teacher_id, teacher_name, email, `status`, prod_id, tca_form_type, prod_company, prod_name FROM table_tmp
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table.status = IF(table.status = 2 and VALUES(status) = 0, table.status, VALUES(status));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should suffice:

```
load data local
infile '".$file."'
replace
into table t1
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"'
(@tid, 
teacher_name, 
email,
@pid,   
tca_form_type, 
prod_company, 
prod_name,
@stts)
set status = if(status = 2 and @stts = 0, status, @stts),
teacher_id = @tid, prod_id = @pid;
```

If this doesn't help, you can try with the [`values()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values), although it says that it's for the  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.

> In an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement, you can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The VALUES() function is meaningful only in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause of INSERT statements and returns NULL otherwise. See Section 13.2.5.3, “INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax”.

If that doesn't help either, please provide the table schema and so on, so we can have a try ourselfs and don't have to guess.

Comment: Your first solution I tried at the beginning, no result.  
With values() function it need to create temporary table, am I right?

Comment: Why should it? I meant to try to use the values function in the load data statement. But inserting into a separate table and then updating your table is of course another possible solution.

Comment: Then I'm not sure how to use the values function in the load data statement. Could you give example?